# How to send parameters to body of the html of a URL from android studio?

Tags: android

I'm able to communicate with the URL but need to send input fields to the  body of the url's html. The way the body parameters are sent in postman similar manner in android studio how can it be done? Kindly share a solution.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Be more specific about your problem

Comment: am I right that you are able to send request through postman, and now want to send same request using Android?

Answer (score 0):

Well you should use some library to make the process easier. There are a lot of options, you could use OkHttp, an Http client that allows you to make calls at low level.

I personally recommend you Retrofit, which includes OkHttp inside of it. Once you understand how to use it it's very simple to implement standard Rest calls. There are tons of guides on the internet, you could search for any, for example:

https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Retrofit/article.html

https://guides.codepath.com/android/consuming-apis-with-retrofit

https://square.github.io/retrofit/

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

> You can Use Retrofit library to pass data in Body as same in Postman: https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-send-objects-in-request-body

```
 @POST("/tasks")
void createTask(@Body Task task, Callback<Task> cb);
```

the @body holds data to send to server

Answer (score 0):

**Try this way on your Apiclient/Api class**

```
    @GET(Url)
    @FormUrlEncoded
    Call<Your Model> mathodname (@Field("parameter name") String object,
                                 @Field("parameter name") String object);
```

hope it will helps